# Calling a tRPC procedure in Next middleware

Tags: next.js, prisma, trpc

I want to call my tRPC procedure in my middleware to redirect users who are authed but haven't signed up yet (in my database). Now I obviously can't do useQuery here because it's not a react component, but I also can't write just an API route that I can call and pass prisma into as middleware sits in both front end and backend. And you can't use the Prisma client on the front end for obvious security reasons.
So I'm a little stuck, I'm sure this is going to be a simple one liner from someone here!

```
import { getAuth, withClerkMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { api } from "./utils/api";
import { appRouter } from "./server/api/root";
import { prisma } from "./server/db";

export default withClerkMiddleware(async (req: NextRequest, opts) => {
 const { userId } = getAuth(req);

 if (userId) {
// Fetch user data from your TRPC client (Replace this with your actual API call)


const user = api.ptusers.getOne({id: userId}).useQuery()

// If user doesn't exist in your database, redirect to sign up page
if (!user) {
  return NextResponse.redirect("/sign-up");
  }
 }

return NextResponse.next();
});

// Stop Middleware running on static files
export const config = {
matcher: "/((?!_next/image|_next/static|favicon.ico|bg-signup.jpg).*)",
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `createTRPCProxyClient` to do the client side call without using hooks, check the [docs](https://trpc.io/docs/client/setup) to learn how to setup the client.

You can also call your procedures directly from the server using the caller api, [caller api docs](https://trpc.io/docs/server/server-side-calls#create-caller).

I am not sure but replacing `userQuery` by `query` might get the job done, of not please try any of the above solutions.

```js
const user = api.ptusers.getOne({id: userId}).query()
```

Don't worry about making server side calls from the middleware function, it doesn't get included in your bundle and gets executed away from the client side.

Comment: Hey Sherif, firstly thank you for your answer. So I attempted the first and second, I managed to get the types to work but now I get another issue with the clerk middleware.

```
     TRPCClientError: You need to use "withClerkMiddleware" in your Next.js 
     middleware file.
```
Despite the fact I'm using it directly there.

I also can't use prisma in the middleware because where it runs on the edge, you then have to set up some data proxy thing here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/data-platform/data-proxy#using-the-data-proxy-in-a-prisma-application